# AWS Redshift Select all except some columns

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, queryselectall

I've got a problem where I want to select all from a table/view except some columns. Is there any way of achieving this without creating a procedure?

Answer (score 4):

No. BigQuery and I think Snowflake might support it, but Redshift doesn't support SELECT * EXCEPT syntax.